# Sorting in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I'm new to Perl and stuck with an  array sorting problem.

For example if my input is

```
@lines =  qw/ S-1.1 A-1.4 V-1.3 /
```

output should be in the order

```
A-1.4, V-1.3, S-1.1.
```

The idea is sort out based on what comes after `-` in the string. I tried `sort {$a <=> $b} @lines` but it did not help.

Please advise some idea to get this done.

Comment: Did you mean `@lines = ("S-1.1", "A-1.4", "V-1.3")`? Why don't you just extract the sort criterion via a regex and do a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_Transform)?

Comment: In your example the sort is based on what is after the `-` in numerically reverse order? Is that what you mean?

Comment: What about [*Sort::Naturally*](https://metacpan.org/module/Sort::Naturally)?

Comment: @amon: He says he's new to Perl and you ask *"Why don't you just extract the sort criterion via a regex and do a Schwartzian Transform?"*!!

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;  
use warnings;

my @lines = ("S-1.1", "A-1.4", "V-1.3"); 
@lines = sort { (split /-/, $b)[1] <=> (split /-/, $a)[1] } @lines; 
print join ', ', @lines;
```

**output**

```
A-1.4, V-1.3, S-1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @lines = qw(S-1.1 A-1.4 V-1.3);
@lines = sort { substr($a, index($a, '-') + 1) <=>
                substr($b, index($b, '-') + 1) } @lines;
print "@lines\n";  #: S-1.1 V-1.3 A-1.4
```

If you want to have more than one dot in the strings, it becomes a bit more complicated:

```
sub pad($) {
  local $_ = $_[0];
  s/^[^-]*?-//;
  s/(\d+)/sprintf("%020d",$1)/ge;  
  $_
}
my @lines = qw(S-1.2.12 B-1.2.9 A-1.4 V-1.3);
@lines = sort { pad($a) cmp pad($b) } @lines;
print "@lines\n";  #: B-1.2.9 S-1.2.12 V-1.3 A-1.4
```